# Maps Activity shows White Screen in release apk but not debug

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I added a maps activity to my application.

I have gone to the console and generated 2 API keys. One for the debug build and one for the release build.

Android Manifest

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Again, I have two keys, one for debug and one for release. I comment out release when debugging and vise versa for release.

When in debug on emulator, maps loads. For reference, I right clicked and added maps activity and had studio generate everything.

MainActivity (Starts the MapsActivity class)

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class));
```

I am not posting the MapsActivity class as it is all boilerplate.

When showing on the emulator the maps load, when showing on the phone (released and uploaded to Google Play, I get a blank white screen.

No errors are shown for debug (which seems to work) and release (which shows the white screen).

I used keytool to view the .jks file that Android creates when building the release to get the SHA1.

I am at a loss on why the maps don't seem to be working in release mode.

Comment: Have you enabled the google maps in the google api's console?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem.  Ultimately I discovered your two keys shouldn't be in the same xml file.  When you switch to 'release' mode, android studio substitutes the debug xml file for a release xml file.  That is where you need to paste your release api key.